# Passing collection name to mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var sensorModel = new Schema({
key: String,
value: Schema.Types.Mixed
})
modules.export = mongoose.model('collectionName',sensorModel);
```

I want to pass the the name of collection from my main app.js file to it then specifying it in the model code, is there a way by which I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it with [`Template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) as below

**sensorModel.js**

```
module.exports = function (modelName) { 
    // sensorModel definition...
    //...

    var str = `${modelName}`;
    mongoose.model(str, sensorModel);
});
```

**app.js**

```
var modelName = 'collectionName';
require('./models/sensorModel.js')(modelName); // require the model file before invoking `mongoose.model`.
var CollectionName = mongoose.model('collectionName');
```

Comment: `var sensorData = require('./models/sensorModel');` how do i pass the collection name to it,